# Wordpress Removing Parent Customizer settings in Child theme

Tags: php, wordpress

In my **parent theme** `functions.php` file some customizer settings have added like this:

```
class Ichi_Customizer extends Youxi_Customize_Manager {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        add_action( 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue_control_scripts' ) );

        add_action( 'customize_register', array( $this, 'color_customizer' ) );

        add_action( 'customize_register', array( $this, 'general_customizer' ) );

        add_action( 'customize_register', array( $this, 'social_customizer' ) );

        add_action( 'customize_register', array( $this, 'typography_customizer' ) );
```

I would like to remove some of them in my child theme, without editing my parent functions.php. I have tried to remove the customizer settings from my **child theme** `functions.php` like this:

```
// Remove settings from parent theme customizer 
function remove_custom( $wp_customize ) {
  remove_action( 'customize_register', array( $this, 'color_customizer' ) );
}

add_action( 'customize_register', 'remove_custom', 1000 );
```

This does not remove the desired customizer setting. What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

Been trying this alternative approach, overriding the whole parent function like this:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', function() {

    class Ichi_Customizer extends Youxi_Customize_Manager {

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();

            remove_action( 'customize_register', array( $this, 'color_customizer' ) );



        }
    }

$GLOBALS[ 'youxi_customize_manager' ] = new Ichi_Customizer();


}, 42 );
```

However, this does not work either!

Answer (score 0):

I thing this can help you...

Change

```
function remove_custom( $wp_customize ) {
  remove_action( 'customize_register', array( $this, 'color_customizer' ) );
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'remove_custom', 1000 );
```

to

```
function remove_custom( $wp_customize ) {
  remove_action( 'customize_register', array( $this, 'color_customizer' ) );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_custom', 0 );
```

Comment: $this refers to the class, so that is not used in the Child theme. See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189484/removing-non-native-customizer-settings-from-a-child-theme